# Extracting/retrieving Email receivers with Excel-vba using MS outlook

Tags: excel

I have an issue with Excel vba communicating with MS outlook. I try to extract the receiver of Emails in my inbox with vba in Excel. I use the property/method obj.To where obj is an Mail-item. This normally works, but it doesn't work with a calendar notification of an email sender. I can't find anything that is wrong with that email. The error message that is produced is "438 run time error: object doesn't support method or property".
I use Win10 and Office 2019 on a Dell labtop. I searched the internet and found that a bug fix ((Microsoft Fix-It # 50356)) could resolve the issue. Do you agree? What else can be done to resolve the issue?

Purpose of my code is to generate PDF-files from historic emails to save outside of the Email system as files.

I appreciate your help.

Regards

Klaus12

Comment: Could you please include your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The code that caused the issue is:

Comment: The code that caused the issue is: ThisWorkbook.Sheets("get_folder_info_xy").Cells(i + 1, 5).Value = obj.to and obj is an email item. I implemented a work around that explicitly handles an exception when run time error 438 occurs. Email items that cause the issue do not have any receiver and I think that was the issue. Those items are e.g. notfications of scheduled meetings.